# Order of checkboxes on secondary PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the following solution which almost fixes my issue:

[Sequential Order of Checkboxes Selected PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660680/)

The solution mentioned works perfectly if you view the results of the `$_POST['col_list']` on the same page.

For me, when the 'submit' button is pressed I am taken to a separate PHP page which displays this and other variables I have input. When I do a `print_r($_POST['col_list'])` I see the correct variables that I selected but in their original order -- not the order in which they were selected.

My question is: how do I carry over the order of the checkboxes I've selected to a separate PHP page?

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/2940778/ could be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you applyed [the solution quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660680/), `$_POST['col_list']` doesn't contain the checkbox selection order, it's `$_POST['order']` which does. If you `print_r([$_POST['order'])`, you'll see your selection order.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you linked will not change the order of the values in the `$_POST` array.
If you write the input inside the `<form>` element as indicated in the solution, you will get another value (`$_POST['order']`) inside the `$_POST` array containing the order for the checkboxes (which should look like ",host,atom_name").

It is up to you to reorder the elements in your array, based on this value (I would suggest creating a new array, as changing the `$_POST` array is bad practice).